# Image not imported from CSV in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, product-images, import, csv, import-products

**I want to import some product with images with CSV so i have add my image in**

```
var/www/html/mag/var/import/images
```

folder with lamptest.jpg name and added filename with

```
base_image , small_image , thumbnail_image , swatch_image with lamptest.jpg name in both configurable and virtual product.
```

My product is imported with correct info. but image is not imported with this.

Anyone suggest me what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add your images under /var/import/images/product_images
2. Add this path in the images file directory field during upload the file
   [image: Images fiel directory fiel]

Magento's default directory is var/import/images.

If you are uploading images under var/import/images directory then no need to mention directory path in the "Images File Directory" field.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Yes you are correct my actual problem was i think i have not given correct permission to pub/media folder then i solve that and thanks for your suggestion also.

Comment: Glad to hear you did successfully. Cheers !!